# Is Glee on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I would think it was obviously on-topic, but I can't find any Glee questions when I search.

Is Glee on topic? If not, why?

Comment: Is Glee a TV show? - Really, you're better off asking the question first and then coming to meta if the question gets closed for some reason.

Comment: Every TV show is on topic and movie too, no need to think of genre and language.

Comment: The fact there are no questions about *Glee* doesn't mean it's off-topic. There are millions of on-topic films and TV-shows noone asked a question about yet.

Answer (score 5):

As long as the question relates to the [on-topic guidelines](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there is no reason why a question about Glee would not be on-topic.  There is nothing particular about Glee that makes it off-topic.